# Vue-query returned data is read only. How to make it mutable?

Tags: vue.js, vue-query

```
import { useQuery } from "vue-query";
const { isLoading, data /* read only */, error, isError, refetch } = useQuery("todo", todo)
```

I just found out data returned by vue-query is read only. Vue-query is similary project to React-query. You can [find it here](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/vue/guides/queries).
If I do `data.todoList.push(newTodo)`
then I got the following warning

> [Vue warn] Set operation on key "xxx" failed: target is readonly

My question is 1) How do I change the value returned by vue-query?
2) If I need to change the returned data, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: I don't know Vue at all, but why do you need to mutate it? Can't you just do `[...data.todoList, newTodo]`?

Comment: [...data.todoList, newTodo] does not work, same warning, no effect. I am not familiar with correct pattern for vue-query. Why they make the returned data read only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is intentional to NOT be able to change the returned content, see [github issue](https://github.com/TanStack/query/issues/4750).

just save/copy the returned data into a reactive variable and modify it as u wish.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for me, even if I used the [...] operator. What did work was using the toRaw function from Vue, to remove the proxy wrapper around each object before assigning the data to my reactive variable.

```js
watch(
  () => productsQuery.data.value,
  (newData) => {
    products.value = toRaw(newData ?? []);
  }
);
```